# Does Gradle have a way to check the checksum of jar after it has been downloaded from the Maven repo?

Tags: gradle, checksum

I'm looking for something in Gradle that is analogous to Maven's

> -C, --strict-checksums
>   Fail the build if checksums don’t match

Something that will fail the build if the download jar file doesn't match what is published in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

There's checksum-dependency-plugin which is a more powerful than Witness (see https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins#checksum-dependency-plugin ). checksum-dependency-plugin can verify both checksums and PGP signatures. It supports both dependencies and plugins.

Gradle 6.2 would probably include its own way to verify checksums.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for that in Gradle 5.4 and before.

You may find the following plugin of interest though: https://github.com/signalapp/gradle-witness